# Get Value from option drop down and use the value in a formula using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to grab an information from option value and use the value as (if, if else) in javascript, however it seems something is wrong as when I run the function(), no value is shown. I grab the option value using
:

```
var j = document.getElementById("size").value;
        var size =  j.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var k = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var type =  k.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

however, there are no value return when I run the codes
..

Please find my codes down below:

//html

```
<table style="text-align: center;">
    <tr>
        <th>PRODUCT SAMPLE</th>
        <th>PRODUCT SPECIFICATION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan ="4">
        <img src ="flyers.png" style ="width: 30%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p>Select Paper Size</p>
        <select name = "size" id ="size">
            <option value ="A3" id="A3" name="A3">A3</option>
            <option value ="A4" id="A4" name="A4">A4</option>
            <option value ="A5" id="A5" name="A5">A5</option>
        </select>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p>Select Paper Type</p>
        <select name = "type" id ="type">
            <option value ="simili 80 gsm" id="simili 80 gsm" name="simili 80 gsm">Simili 80 GSM</option>
            <option value ="simili 70 gsm" id="simili 70 gsm" name="simili 70 gsm">Simili 70 GSM</option>
            <option value ="art paper 128gsm" id="art paper 128gsm" name="art paper 128gsm">Art Paper 128GSM</option>
        </select>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p>Insert Quantity</p>
        <input type="number" id="txt3" name="text3" placeholder="quantity eg: 1000, 2000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<br> 
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

//javascript

```
<script>
        var a; //A3 Simili 80 GSM
        var b; //A3 Simili 70 GSM
        var c; //A3 Art Paper 128 GSM
        var d; //A4 Simili 80 GSM
        var e; //A4 Simili 70 GSM
        var f; //A4 Art Paper 128 GSM
        var g; //A5 Simili 80 GSM
        var h; //A5 Simili 70 GSM
        var i; //A5 Art Paper 128 GSM
        var j; //value size
        var size;
        var k; //value type
        var type;
        var l; //value of quantity (txt3)
        var m; //answer for A3 Simili 80 GSM
        var n; //answer for A3 Simili 70 GSM
        var o; //answer for A3 Art Paper 128 GSM
        var p;
        var q;
        var r;
        var s;
        var t;
        var u;
        var v;
        var w;
        var x;
        var y;
        var z;



        function myFunction() {
        var a = 0.8;
        var b = 0.7;
        var c = 1.0;
        var d = 0.7;
        var e = 0.6;
        var f = 0.9;
        var g = 0.6;
        var h = 0.5;
        var i = 0.8;
        var j = document.getElementById("size").value;
        var size =  j.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var k = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var type =  k.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var l = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
        var m = a * +l;
        var n = b * +l;
        var o = c * +l;

        if (var size = A3){
            if (var type = simili 80 gsm){

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Grand Total : RM " + m + "<br><br>";

            }
            else if (var type = simili 70 gsm){

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Grand Total : RM " + n + "<br><br>";

            }

            else{

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Grand Total : RM " + o + "<br><br>";

            }
        }

        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Grand Total : RM " + q + "<br><br>";

        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "Total Weight for all : " + r + " KG";

         }
    </script>
```

Thank you in Advance, any help is appreciated..

Comment: Your conditionals need two (or three) equals signs (`==` or `===`). You're **overriding** a variable rather than **assigning** to it when you write `if (var size = A3)` and so on, meaning that the conditions will always evaluate to `true`. This would be more obvious if you used meaningful variable names, rather than `var a` through `var z` (which you're also overriding within the function).

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comments @ObsidianAge, I've tried stacking the equals signs and removing the "var", letting the variable name only ex: (size == "A3"), however it doesn't work, thanks you..

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comments @JeroenHeier, unfortunately I didn't debug my code as I only use notepad++ as my codes scripting.. Thank you

Comment: Hi @muhammadamiruldin, you should check out jsfiddle.net or similar, they are perfect for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is wrong with code in the question? (Below is the solution):

1. Variables a-z are defined in the body of the script but a-o are redefined in the function body, this will cause a scope issue as the redefined a-o only exist in the function scope, if the script is not using them outside of the function scope they do not need to be declared outside of the function body.
2. In the below lines, the script gets the **value** of the **size** element then tries to get the **options** property of the **value** of **size**. This will be null. e.g.

   ```
   //wrong (see 2 and 3)
   var j = document.getElementById("size").value;
   var size =  j.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

   //right
   var j = document.getElementById("size");
   var size =  j.options[j.selectedIndex].text;
   ```
3. also note in the above lines, the wrong example uses the **e** variable to get the **selectedIndex** property, this is not correct, e is a float and does not contain a **selectedIndex** property, I believe you wanted the property of **j**
   (see right answer)
4. Also in the lines above, the wrong example is using the **value** property of the **options[i]** element, when it should be using the **text** property.
5. In this line, there is a syntax error, the script is trying to define **size** again where the compiler expects a boolean. e.g.

   ```
   //wrong (see 5, 6 and 7)
   if (var size = A3){

   //right
   if (size == "A3"){
   ```
6. Notice in the above code, the wrong example is also trying to set the **size** variable, not check it, the **=** operator generally sets a variable to the right side parameter (unless overloaded for other purposes)
7. Also in the above code, the script is missing quotation marks around **A3**, it should be **"A3"** to specify a string value, not a variable named A3.
8. The same is done on the next line and on various other lines, the script does not match the casing of the options from the HTML element. String comparison is not case insensitive and when comparing two strings of different casing, the strings need to be converted to match (look into the String.toUpperCase() function) otherwise the string casing must match e.g.

   ```
   //wrong (see 5,6,7 and 8)
   if (var type = simili 80 gsm){

   //right
   if (type == "Simili 80 GSM"){
   ```

There is some other VERY minor issues, but this is the bulk of the problem and why I decided to rewrite the code from scratch, hope that helps.

### SOLUTION

You can build on this code. I hope it helps.
I have included comments for clarity.

### How to add new items:

Anywhere after var data = []; (where the collection is initialised)
You can add the following (for example):

Here I am adding a new item, A4 Simili 70 GSM, costing 0.90 RM each and weighing 0.45KG each.

```
data.push({
    size: "A4",
    type: "Simili 70 GSM",
    cost: 0.90,
    weig: 0.45
});
```

### The full code:

Replace your script with this:

```
    <script>
    //initialise an array and push in the size-type-cost-weight pairs
    //the values here are for example only
    var data = [];
    data.push({
        size: "A3",
        type: "Simili 80 GSM",
        cost: 0.8,
        weig: 0.5
    });
    data.push({
        size: "A3",
        type: "Simili 70 GSM",
        cost: 0.7,
        weig: 0.4
    });
    data.push({
        size: "A3",
        type: "Art Paper 128GSM",
        cost: 1.0,
        weig: 0.8
    });

    //declare the function you call when submitting the selections
    function myFunction()
    {
        //get the elements
        var sizeElem = document.getElementById("size");
        var typeElem = document.getElementById("type");
        var qtyElem = document.getElementById("txt3");

        //get the values
        var size = sizeElem.options[sizeElem.selectedIndex].text
        var type = typeElem.options[typeElem.selectedIndex].text
        var qty = qtyElem.value;

        //set a default value
        var foundValue = 0;
        var foundWeight = 0;

        //iterate through each item in the data collection
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var ie = data[i];
            if(ie.size == size && ie.type == type)
            {
                foundValue = ie.cost;
                foundWeight = ie.weig;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(foundValue > 0 && foundWeight > 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Grand Total : RM " + (foundValue * qty) + "<br><br>";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Total Weight for all : " + (foundWeight * qty) + " KG";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Selection not valid";
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you @ aaronedmistone, your answer works!! May I know how to add other variables such as A4 70 GSM Simili.. Thank you in advance

Comment: no problem @muhammadamiruldin I will update my answer to cover your question, thanks for accepting as answer.

Comment: Hi @muhammadamiruldin, I have updated the answer to explain how to add new items. hope that helps. You will of course need to add them to the HTML option lists as well with the EXACT same name, spelling and casing.

Comment: Hi @aaromedmistone , thank you so much! But may I know why my codes didn't work, I've tried putting double equal sign ex: (size == "A3") and (size === "A3"), but they didn't work.. Thank you in advance

Comment: @muhammadamiruldin do you mean your original code? I can edit my answer to list the issues if you like?

If you mean the new code, I made a jsfiddle page for you, perhaps you could make/test the changes there? This way I could point you in the right direction.

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronedmistone/og1eck2q/

Comment: Hi @aaronedmistone, I mean my original codes.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @aaronedmistone, Thank you SOOOO much dude! I will try to rewrite my original code for understanding purposes.. Im truly grateful to you man, If I can upvote you, I would have already, but my rep still not enough, sorry man.. Nonetheless, Thank you so much

Comment: No problem man, good luck with it, you will have it down in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are incorrect. An if statement checks a particular condition `if(condition) {// do code}`
However, you are declaring variables rather than writing a condition in your if statement.

So you need to change your if statements like so:

```
if (size == "A3") {
    if (type == "simili 80 gsm") {
      // do code..
    } else if (type == "simili 70 gsm") {
      // do code...
    }
}
```

Comment: [edited to be brief] - there is more problems in the code unfortunately, also a switch case might be a better option than nested if statements. He has case sensitive issues, syntax errors and incorrect objects and variables used and other issues.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer @Nick Parsons, unfortunately I've tried that before, but no luck, thanks